# Ruby 1.9.3 Teeny Version

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

When using RBConfig to determine my ruby version, I get the "wrong" teeny version when using ruby 1.9.3:

```
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]
# ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(MAJOR))'
1
# ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(MINOR))'
9
# ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(TEENY))'
1
```

Using Ruby 1.8.7 - this works fine:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts Config::CONFIG.fetch(%q(MAJOR))'
1
$ ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts Config::CONFIG.fetch(%q(MINOR))'
8
$ ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts Config::CONFIG.fetch(%q(TEENY))'
7
```

I know I can get patchlevel and use that a bit, but why is ruby 1.9.3 returning 1 as its teeny version?

Comment: I am using `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]` and am getting the same `TEENY` error as you are, using both `Config` and `RbConfig`

Comment: I think it is because the 1.9.3 is based on 1.9.1 - as is ruby 1.9.2, but cannot find any documents stating why.  I would like to know how to properly check for 1.9.3 - should I check patch or revision?

Comment: I think this is because the linked libraries are still using ruby 1.9.1 as the version, can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby has two concepts of version: The actual release version, and the "compatibility version". For all Rubies 1.9.1 -> 1.9.3, the compatibility version is `1.9.1`, because they are all backward compatible with the `1.9.1` release.

The `RUBY_VERSION`constant contains the release version number, but you will need to split the dots to get the MAJOR, MINOR, and TEENY if those values are important to you:

```
>> major, minor, teeny = RUBY_VERSION.split(".")
=> ["1", "9", "3"]
>> teeny
=> "3"
```

That said, Ruby version numbers are specifically designed to be ASCII-comparable, so it is common to see code like this for simple version checks:

```
if RUBY_VERSION >= "1.9.3"
  #...
end
```

Patch level can typically be ignored, because there are no API changes in patch level releases, only bug fixes and security patches. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Minor is just reporting on the library minor - ok.  So all I am left with is the ruby_version string - better than nothing.

```
# /usr/bin/ruby -rrbconfig -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(LIBRUBY_SO))'
libruby.so.1.9.1
# /usr/bin/ruby -rrbconfig -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(ruby_version))'
1.9.3-p286
```

ruby 1.8 shows this:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -rrbconfig -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(LIBRUBY_SO))'
libruby1.8.so.1.8.7
```

and ruby 1.9.2-p320 this:

```
$ ruby -rrbconfig -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG.fetch(%q(LIBRUBY_SO))'
libruby.so.1.9.1
```

So I guess mystery solved.