# ruby TypeError can't convert Date into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine-plugins

I get `TypeError (can't convert Date into String)` in ruby, using `irb` i test & can get the desired value, but inside redmine's graph plugin i get the above error.

ruby version is 1.9.3p0, but i get this error log:

```
TypeError (can't convert Date into String):
plugins/redmine_graphs/app/controllers/graphs_controller.rb:130:in `parse'
plugins/redmine_graphs/app/controllers/graphs_controller.rb:130:in `block in issue_growth_graph'
plugins/redmine_graphs/app/controllers/graphs_controller.rb:126:in `each'
plugins/redmine_graphs/app/controllers/graphs_controller.rb:126:in `issue_growth_graph'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal
/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
```

another question is my ruby version is 1.9.3p0, but in logs i get 1.91, why this happens?

following piece of code in redmine's graph plugin causes this:

```
# Displays projects by total issues over time
def issue_growth_graph

    # Initialize the graph
    graph = SVG::Graph::TimeSeries.new({
        :area_fill => true,
        :height => 300,
        :min_y_value => 0,
        :no_css => true,
        :show_x_guidelines => true,
        :scale_x_integers => true,
        :scale_y_integers => true,
        :show_data_points => false,
        :show_data_values => false,
        :stagger_x_labels => true,
        :style_sheet => "/plugin_assets/redmine-graphs-plugin/stylesheets/issue_growth.css",
        :width => 720,
        :x_label_format => "%Y-%m-%d"
    })

    # Get the top visible projects by issue count
    sql = "SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) as issue_count"
    sql << " FROM issues"
    sql << " LEFT JOIN #{Project.table_name} ON #{Issue.table_name}.project_id = #{Project.table_name}.id"
    sql << " WHERE (%s)" % Project.allowed_to_condition(User.current, :view_issues)
    unless @project.nil?
        sql << " AND (project_id = #{@project.id}"
        sql << "    OR project_id IN (%s)" % @project.descendants.active.visible.collect { |p| p.id }.join(',') unless @project.descendants.active.visible.empty?
        sql << " )"
    end 
    sql << " GROUP BY project_id"
    sql << " ORDER BY issue_count DESC"
    sql << " LIMIT 6"
    top_projects = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql).collect { |p| p["project_id"] }

    # Get the issues created per project, per day
    sql = "SELECT project_id, date(#{Issue.table_name}.created_on) as date, COUNT(*) as issue_count"
    sql << " FROM #{Issue.table_name}"
    sql << " WHERE project_id IN (%s)" % top_projects.compact.join(',')
    sql << " GROUP BY project_id, date"
    issue_counts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql).group_by { |c| c["project_id"] }

    # Generate the created_on lines
    top_projects.each do |project_id, total_count|
        counts = issue_counts[project_id].sort { |a,b| a["date"]<=>b["date"] }         
        created_count = 0
        created_on_line = Hash.new
        #the place of error is following error
        created_on_line[(Date.parse(counts.first["date"])-1).to_s] = 0
        counts.each { |count| created_count += count["issue_count"].to_i; created_on_line[count["date"]] = created_count }
        created_on_line[Date.today.to_s] = created_count
        graph.add_data({
            :data => created_on_line.sort.flatten,
            :title => Project.find(project_id).to_s
        })
    end

    # Compile the graph
    headers["Content-Type"] = "image/svg+xml"
    send_data(graph.burn, :type => "image/svg+xml", :disposition => "inline")
end
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273773/ruby-1-9-3-teeny-version for the answer to the version number part. Looks like the block for `top_projects.each` is where the error pops up. You can either use the debugger, or open that file and stick in some warnings or use something like pry (e.g. `binding.pry`) to see what's happening.

Comment: thanks for the tip, finally i change the query & now everything is working, really i return string from query and not date

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now. Is the query yours and not the library's? If so, I'd suggest strongly you use an ORM or some kind of data connection library, as it will be far more secure that way. I'd recommend Sequel.