# Failing deploy with RVM + unicorn

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm, unicorn

I'm trying to setup a Sinatra App with unicorn.
After following [this example](http://tech.tulentsev.com/2012/03/deploying-with-sinatra-capistrano-unicorn/)
and adjusting it to my needs, I've gotten this error:

```
<my_path_name>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.8.0/lib/kgio.rb:21:in 'require': cannot load such file -- kgio_ext (LoadError)
```

I'm using `rvm 1.18.5`, `ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-linux]` and the latest release of `unicorn 4.5.0` which pulls `kgio 2.8.0`

The OS is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6`.
I've also tried with `ruby-1.9.3-p125`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510386/cant-launch-rails-app-via-unicorn-due-to-kgio-ext-loaderror), maybe try one of those ideas.

Did the gem install go smoothly?

Comment: bundle install runs with no problem. I've tried to use Thin instead but I've hit a similar problem :\ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610091/thin-eventmachine-fails-to-start)