# Rails - cannot run app: Unable to load the EventMachine C extension;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, eventmachine

When I run an app on Lion OS X, I get this error:

```
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubyeventmachine (LoadError)
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/rubydev/future_computers/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'adam
```

I don't really know how to fix this, I've added the `eventmachine` gem into the Gemfile, but it didn't help...

Could you help me, please, how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you got any errors with `bundle install`?

Comment: `bundle install` works without any errors.

Answer (score 19):

In my case this fixed it:

- $ gem uninstall eventmachine
- at the prompt tell it to uninstall all versions (it tells you about dependencies)
- $ bundle install

I was reading through this https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/333. There were problems with eventmachine, so making sure I got the newest version seemed a good idea.

Comment: This didn't work for me - I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 9):

For me, compiling eventmachine from sources with [tweaked config](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/186#issuecomment-1051918) helped. Try:

Uninstall eventmachine if it's already installed:

```
gem uninstall eventmachine
```

Fetch eventmachine sources:

```
git clone https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
cd eventmachine
```

Edit `ext/extconf.rb` and `ext/fastfilereader/extconf.rb` files by adding `CONFIG['CXX'] = "g++"` right after `require 'mkmf'`

Compile and install gem:

```
rake gem
gem install pkg/eventmachine-1.0.3.gem
```

Now eventmachine should work just fine :)

Comment: this worked for mailcatcher to start but somehow broke my bundle install.. figuring that atm

Comment: Checked out v1.0.3 and performed the edits. Now I am getting a `Don't know how to build task 'native:eventmachine:x86-mingw32' (see --tasks)`

Comment: Elijah are you running Windows? The changes worked for me on macOS. This might help you: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/531

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix as the message says is just to `require 'em/pure_ruby'`. I think you can put this in the **config/inlitializers** folder, you can call the file **event_machine.rb**

But it won't have the same performance as the C extension.

Comment: But where to find & download that file?

Comment: create it inside config/initializers folder

Answer (score 1):

I had that error when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --trace` on Jekyll.4.2.1-Ruby.3.0.3p137(mingw)-Windows. I ran `gem install eventmachine --platform=ruby` and it compiled at `C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.2.7` but when you run `bundle install` it creates also `C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32` . The command `bundle info eventmachine` gives me `C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32` and that's confimed in the Gemfile.lock with the line `eventmachine (1.2.7-x64-mingw32)`. So I changed that line for `eventmachine (1.2.7)` and then the output of `bundle info eventmachine` gives me `C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7` and finally the command `bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --trace` worked ✔️

Comment: Thanks, these steps work for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Providing another solution as I just wasted hours tracking this issue down. I was doing `bundle install --deployment` and then committing the result to a separate branch in git so I could deploy this branch straight to servers without having to do `bundle install` again.

The problem is that eventmachine has a `.gitignore` file in it which tells git to ignore all `*.so` files. Because of this when I was committing, the `.so` files didn't commit, and wouldn't show up as untracked in a `git status`. Also since the gemspec was present, bundle thought the package was completely installed.

My solution was to add a command as part of the build process to go and whack all the `.gitignore` files in the gems before committing.

Comment: using git to store a lot of binary files might be headed for pain

Comment: @BlakeMiller Yeah, we ended up abandoning this method and are building tarballs now.

Answer (score 0):

You may find various errors while installing gems or trying to find solution to your ruby application installation failing due to ruby-devel was not installed.

I just installed on my Kali linux with

sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

and everything resolved. I was trying to install bettercap.

This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502672/6503117