# Error installing eventmachine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I run `foreman start` i get the following error:

```
pallav@pallav-System-Product-Name:~/Workspace/Aadvisor$ foreman start
10:04:32 web.1  | started with pid 11022 10:04:32 web.1  |
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in
`block in materialize': Could not find eventmachine-0.12.10 in any of
the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) 10:04:32 web.1  |  from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
`map!' 10:04:32 web.1  |  from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
`materialize' 10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in
`specs' 10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in
`specs_for' 10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in
`requested_specs' 10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in
`requested_specs' 10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in
`setup' 10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in
`<top (required)>' 10:04:32 web.1  |  from
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
10:04:32 web.1  |   from
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
10:04:32 web.1  | exited with code 1 10:04:32 system | sending SIGTERM
to all processes SIGTERM received
pallav@pallav-System-Product-Name:~/Workspace/Aadvisor$
```

i also did

```
sudo bundle install
```

again error:
"An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10' succeeds before bundling. "

now when i do

```
sudo gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'
```

i again get error which says:

```
"ERROR: Error installing eventmachine: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."
```

Please tell me what i'm missing.

Comment: Please also check : [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19oRqc21Pwt7Cpr3zkjg_9iowYymhg0B2cgOljswLcvY/edit)gem_make.out

Comment: Error logs [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13qbxcOigzUSfQTwk4p_3AwPbAQLDFMZJiIPReOfbifI/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing openssl and libstdc++.
If you are using rvm and have installed ruby in single user mode, you should omit sudo.

Can you paste the complete log of the error?  Would be easier to answer your question with that.

**UPDATE**
Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386686/846970 in another stackoverflow thread and let me know if it works.

Comment: Error logs : https://docs.google.com/document/d/13qbxcOigzUSfQTwk4p_3AwPbAQLDFMZJiIPReOfbifI/edit

Comment: Also your OS details, ruby version

Comment: Linux pallav-System-Product-Name 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: can not find "project.h" file location and 'gem install eventmachine' did not helped.

Comment: sudo updatedb; and then try locate project.h.  This might help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43021/discussion-between-r-a-j-and-pallavsharma)

Answer (score 8):

In order to install *eventmachine 1.0.3* on Ubuntu 14.04 you first need to run:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

then `bundle install` or `gem install eventmachine`

should be enough.

Note: If you have rbenv, remember to run `rbenv rehash` after a `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

try `gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1`

Comment: Thank you. For me it was: gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl\@1.1/1.1.1o/

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac M1/M2, try the following:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-ldflags="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup"
```

Comment: That works for me on macOS Ventura 13.2.1 with M2. Thanks @mallet

Comment: Thanks! Only way works for me with M1 on Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bundle install` you don't have one of the gems required in your Gemfile installed on your machine.

Comment: i did bundle install but now i get another error which says:"An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
"

Comment: and when i try doing `sudo gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'`it again prompt a new error which says "ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Comment: that could be the problem you can try running `gcc` on the command line it should prompt you to install the command line utils.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your system RubyGems.

1. rvm get stable
2. rvm rubygems latest

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who cannot solve with the described above methods:

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -w\"
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle config build.thin --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -w\"
```

As described by user enrico [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1051#issuecomment-9176547).