# Ruby gem eventmachine unable to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, eventmachine

A package containing a bundle of a lot of technologies was delivered to me. When i try install the bundle using  `bundle install --local` there is an error displayed that the eventmachine was not installed properly and suggests that the `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` should be run. When i do that the folloing message is shown:

```
$ gem install eventmachine
Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error

installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... no
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating rubyeventmachine-x64-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming
w32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:60,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from em.h:24,
                 from project.h:150,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../
x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/types.h:68:16: error: conflicting declaration 'ty
pedef _pid_t pid_t'
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:97:13: error: 'pid_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef int pid_t
'
In file included from project.h:151:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
ed.h: In member function 'void EventableDescriptor::SetSocketInvalid()':
ed.h:43:40: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/event
machine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext
/gem_make.out
```

Inside the gem_make.out the following text is shown:

```
c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... no
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating rubyeventmachine-x64-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:60,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from em.h:24,
                 from project.h:150,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/types.h:68:16: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef _pid_t pid_t'
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:97:13: error: 'pid_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef int pid_t'
In file included from project.h:151:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
ed.h: In member function 'void EventableDescriptor::SetSocketInvalid()':
ed.h:43:40: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
```

Anyone got a clue of what this might be?

I have installed ruby 2.0.0 with DevKit. Both in the 64 bit version.

Comment: Beside that problem you should really use a unix based system to run rails. For development windows might work but you cant really run rails in production on windows.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Tried that one now, but it seems to mess up something that has to do with bundler. Right now the bundler doesn't find the gemfile required when i try to bundle install --local.

Comment: @davidb: The bundle was used on a Mac before it got to me. All i need to do is actually just to install the required gems (compass, sass, middleman, etc.) to render the markup and after that i can actually remove it again. I need a quick workaround.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Uninstalled the gem and then reinstalled it using the generated gem mentioned in that thread. Seems to be a workaround. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean i will set this thread as solved in a couple of days.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)  Actually you should probably just delete this question as it is a duplicate and you didn't need to do anything different from the other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with help from the thread that @GraemeMcLean mentions in the comments above ( [Eventmachine gem install fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361958/eventmachine-gem-install-fail) ) 
This was a weird workaround though, and the authors of the gem should really fix this.