# can't run rails's 'thin' server on windows. Unable to load the EventMachine C extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, thin

I read some instructions here

```
https://coderwall.com/p/fltw9q/use-thin-as-your-default-server-in-rails-app
```

`gem install thin` <-- works for me

I add gem 'thin' into my Gemfile

`bundle install` <-- works for me

(so this question is not the same as a similar one where bundle install didn't work)

I then tried `thin s` or `thin start`

```
C:\rubytest\paramstest1>thin s
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.4/rubyeventm
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/rubyeventmachine.rb:2:in `<top (req
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (require
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/bin/thin:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

I noticed another question from a guy that couldn't install thin, (Though his was on *nix rather than windows). [Rails - cannot run app: Unable to load the EventMachine C extension;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824235/rails-cannot-run-app-unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension)  and an answer suggested adding an rb file that could be called event_machine.rb,  and giving it this require line.   require 'em/pure_ruby'

```
C:\rubytest\paramstest1\config\initializers>type event_machine.rb
require 'em/pure_ruby'
C:\rubytest\paramstest1\config\initializers>
```

It doesn't seem to many any difference, I still get that error

```
C:\rubytest\paramstest1>thin start
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
```

An answer

[Cannot install thin on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649252/cannot-install-thin-on-windows)

suggested

`gem install eventmachine --pre`

```
C:\rubytest\paramstest1>gem install eventmachine --pre
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for eventmachine after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I might've had that one already anyway.

My gemfile has gem 'thin' and  with or without gem 'eventmachine'

I try `thin start` but get the same error

`rails s` also gives that error now!

Comment: trying to remember why I thought 'd try thin in the first place.. maybe a)rails has or had a bug with ressetting the database which I since found a solution for or b)rails in windows is/was slow